# Prevent access of S3 bucket for admin via console

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-security-group

I have some very highly confidential data that i want to store in s3 bucket.
I want to make policies ( bucket or iam whatever required) in such a way that no one ( not even admin) can read the contents of files in that bucket from aws console.
But i will have a program running on my host that needs to put and get data from that s3 bucket.
Also i will be using server side encryption of s3 but i can't use client side encryption of s3.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this;

```
    {
        "Id": "bucketPolicy",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "NotPrincipal": {
                    "AWS": [
                            "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/USERNAME",
                            "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ROLENAME"
                    ]
                },
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
    }
```

For test purposes make sure you replace arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/USERNAME with your user arn. So in case you lock out everybody you can at least perform actions on the bucket.

arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ROLENAME should be replaced by the role arn which is attached to your EC2 instance (I am assuming that is what you mean by host).

Comment: Two problems: explicit deny cannot be overridden by explicit allow, and it is impossible to prevent the root credentials from deleting and then replacing a bucket policy, giving the root credentials a backdoor to the bucket.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are correct I missed the condition in the deny statement. I shall fix it in my answer soon.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot policy is updated. It only allows actions to the bucket for specified user/role.